# What physical system does the Hamiltonian $ H = \frac{q^4p^2}{2\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{q^2}$ describe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

My question is basically in the title: I'm training myself on exams of Hamiltonian mechanics and I had this Hamiltonian $$ H = \frac{q^4p^2}{2\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{q^2},$$ without any interpretation. To which physical system does this Hamiltonian correspond?

Comment: here is a hint, try to figure out some canonical transformation to bring the Hamiltonian in the standard form.

Comment: This is an exercise in Goldstein chapter 9.

Comment: or write the equations of motion and see if they're easier to understand.

Comment: My equations of motion are $\ddot q + \frac{\dot{q}^2}{q} - 2 \frac{\lambda}{\mu}q = 0$. This could be an oscillator but I don't recognize the term $\frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}$.

Comment: @DanielSank : what is the equation your were thinking about ?

Comment: you are close to the answer.

Comment: Another hint: write the corresponding Lagrangian and see if the transformation jumps out there.

Comment: Ok, I did find an Hamiltonian $K = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2 \mu}}(\tilde{p}^2 + \tilde{q}^2)$ after a well-chosen canonical transformation. This was the next exercise, and even if it is really natural afterward I don't think I would think about it by myself. Thanks everyone for the awesome help !!
@Javier : the lagrangian I found was $L = \frac{\mu \dot{q}^2}{2q^4} - \frac{\lambda}{q^2}$ and I did used for having equation of motion. Did you suggested me to apply a change of variable to $q$ ? Or was it possible to deduce something already from $L$ ?